# MochaJS Error when using Context - receiving undefined instance

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

I'm writing a test for my `nodeJS` app that is checking to see if a `sequelize` model has all of the defined properties.

When I run the test, I'm getting an error back about the context not being defined.

I'm using the following library to help check the models. 
[sequelize-test-helpers](https://github.com/davesag/sequelize-test-helpers/tree/e1a5c1cf835be7592161047623e1a26830215dcc)

Is this error being thrown something from `Mocha` that I am not defining correctly?

```
// Model
'use strict'

const model = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const Communications = sequelize.define(
        'Communications', 
        {
        recordID: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        messageUUID: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            unique: true,
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        age: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        department: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        campus: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        state: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        partition: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        offset: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        }
    })

    return Communications

}

module.exports = model





// Test
describe('models/Communication', function () {
    const Comm = Communication(sequelize, dataTypes)
    const comm = new Comm()
    checkModelName(Comm)('Communications')

    context('properties', function () {
        ;['recordID', 'messageUUID', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'age', 'department', 'campus', 'state', 'partition', 'offset'].forEach(
            checkPropertyExists(comm)
        )
    }) 

});

Error Returned =  ReferenceError: context is not defined
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substitute context for describe if you do not use mocha, since context is a synonym for mocha.

check here the same answer by one of the contributors of sequelize-test-helpers

https://github.com/davesag/sequelize-test-helpers/issues/111

Comment: Thanks, I made this change to describe instead. I was using Mocha though so I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.